# What's equivalent writing of PRELOAD on fish shell?

Tags: shell, fish, protoc, ld-preload

protoc depends on higer version of libstdc++. Usually on bash shell we writes:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/root/.conda/envs/myfish/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.26 thirdparty/protobuf/bin/protoc
```

I try to use fish shell to do the same thing.

```
⋊> /h/m/rank4 on master ⨯ set LD_PRELOAD /root/.conda/envs/myfish/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.26 thirdparty/protobuf/bin/protoc                                                                                                  (base) 15:02:02
⋊> /h/m/rank4 on master ⨯ echo $LD_PRELOAD                                                                                                                                                                                (base) 15:02:10
/root/.conda/envs/myfish/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.26 thirdparty/protobuf/bin/protoc
```

However, fish shell doesnot recongize the space between word `libstdc++.so.6.0.26` and word `thirdparty`.
The expect behavior is that script uses `LD_PRELOAD` library and executes command `protoc`.
What's the right writing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the same code:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/root/.conda/envs/myfish/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.26 thirdparty/protobuf/bin/protoc
```

Since fish 3.1, that'll just work.

---

> set LD_PRELOAD /root/.conda/envs/myfish/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.26 thirdparty/protobuf/bin/protoc

Sets the variable "LD_PRELOAD" to the values "/root/.conda/envs/myfish/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.26" and "thirdparty/protobuf/bin/protoc"

It doesn't recognize "thirdparty/protobuf/bin/protoc" as a command, just as another argument to the `set` command and hence another value for the variable.

If you do need to use a separate `set` (like in fish < 3.1), you need to *first set the variable*, and then *run the command*. In addition, you need to "export" the variable so that the command you run actually receives a copy. So the code is:

```
set -x LD_PRELOAD /root/.conda/envs/myfish/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.26
thirdparty/protobuf/bin/protoc
# and now erase $LD_PRELOAD again:
set -e LD_PRELOAD
```

or, alternatively, open a new block make a local $LD_PRELOAD so it is erased automatically at the end:

```
begin
    # the "-l" makes the variable local,
    # the "-x" passes it to external commands
    set -lx LD_PRELOAD /root/.conda/envs/myfish/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.26
    thirdparty/protobuf/bin/protoc
end
```

Comment: "Since fish 3.1, that'll just work" -- alternately use the `env` command for the same purpose: `env VAR=value VAR2=value2 /some/command`